# How fast is operation on KeyCollection returned by Dictionary.Keys ? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary, complexity-theory

[`IDictionary<TK, TV>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) defines method [`IDictionary.ContainsKey(in TK)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx) and property [`IDictionary.Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ebzfbyx.aspx) (of type `ICollection`).
I'm interested in (asymptotic) complexity of this method and property in [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implementation of [`IDictionary<TK, TV>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx).

Consider definitions

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int k = new Random().Next();
```

and consider that we have added to the dictionary `dict` `n` unique `KeyValuePair`s.

What is expected (asymptotic) complexity of a call `dict.ContainsKey(k)`? I hope it's in `O(1)` but I did not find it in [documentation of `Dictionary.ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx).

What is expected (asymptotic) complexity of call `dict.Keys.Contains(k)`? I hope it's in `O(1)`but I did not find it in [documentation of `Dictionary.Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) nor in [documentation of `Dictionary.KeyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx). If it is in `O(1)` I don't understand why type of `IDictionary.Keys` property is `ICollection` and not `ISet` (like in Java for example).

Comment: Note: `ISet<T>` is new with .NET 4, `ICollection<T>` and `IDictionary<T, K>` have been around since .NET 2.

Comment: Anthony Pegram: then I hope they will change the type of `IDictionary.Keys` to `ISet` in .NET 5.

Comment: that would be a breaking change for many customers. They're not going to do that. With that said, remember, it's just an interface, it can be implemented by anything. Indeed, to implement `ISet<T>`, you *must* implement `ICollection<T>`. Therefore, the actual object returned could very well implement `ISet<T>`. The interface type returned says nothing of the implementation details, merely the contract that is ackhowledged as fulfilled.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: That is all understood (except of "breaking change for many customers" - I do not consider this good reason). However the actual object returned (`KeyCollection`) does not implement `ISet<T>` and I think it should. What is more I think that its type should be `ISet<T>` when the type is `ICollection<T>` the programer typically think of something like `List` and (in my case for example) ask question about complexity on SO :). However returned collection has typical attribute of set: quick answer to "do you contain some element" without enumeration so the type should correspond.

Comment: If they could do it over, they would likely change it. But a new framework version *is not carte blanche to undo past ills.* You may not think it, but avoiding the breaking change is one of the most important things to consider. That is not to say Microsoft has never and will never introduce a breaking change into .NET, but the benefits have to be beyond enormous. But the fact is they can have their cake and eat it, too. They return an interface, the implementation details thereof do not have to be constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `IDictionary<K,V>` is only an interface, not an implementation, then it doesn't provide any performance guarantees.

For the built-in `Dictionary<K,V>` type, the [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) method should be O(1):

> [This method approaches an O(1) operation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

The [`Keys.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673071.aspx) method actually calls the parent dictionary's `ContainsKey` method, so that should also be O(1):

> [This method is an O(1) operation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673071.aspx)

*(Both quotes are taken from the "Remarks" section of the relevant documentation pages.)*

Comment: @Mehrdad: I actually made my edit simultaneously with yours, after I noticed the OP's comment on your answer.

Comment: Ah sorry about that then... it wasn't obvious what exactly happened, my bad.

Comment: The Dictionary really is not O(1). It's O(log n) http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/performance-of-generics-sorteddictionary-and-dictionary/

Answer (score 5):

The [first link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) you provided says, in the Remarks:

> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

Also, if you click on the [`Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673071.aspx) you'll see the same thing in the remarks:

> This method is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Oh well sorry I should read more carefully. But the second question about `Keys.Contains` has no answer in documentation at leas I cannot find it.

Comment: @drasto: Actually, [that one also says the same thing in the remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673071.aspx).