# Using IEnumerable.Except on KeyCollection vs. exploiting Dictionary.ContainsKey for mutual subtractions and intersection in relation to performance

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I have two dictionaries `Dictionary<string, object>`. I need to find their intersection (I mean only their keys intersection) and A\B and B\A subtractions and make some actions to the objects (in fact my objects are EntityFramework entities and I have to mark their state as `Modified`, `Added` and `Deleted` respectively, though it's not very relevant to the question). Just imagine the simplest [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

I want to do it the most efficient way. I think I have two choices:

1) Implement a set of generic extension methods that internally operate `IEnumerable` methods on `KeyCollection` like `ExceptByKey`, for example:

```c#
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ExceptByKeys<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict1, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2)
{
    return dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys).ToDictionary(key => key, key => dict1[key]);
}
```

Then I could operate these methods to separately process each of three groups. From [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671512/how-fast-is-operation-on-keycollection-returned-by-dictionary-keys-net) I know that `KeyCollection.Contains` method internally uses the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey` method so both are O(1). So my `Except` method would then run in O(n), **is that right?** I would need to use it once for each dictionary and also somehow detect the intersected part, which can be done implicitly though by first iterating over all entities in one dictionary and marking them as belonging to the intersection. So, is it like O(n) + O(n + m)?

2) I could also iterate over my dictionaries calling `ContainsKey` method on the other dictionary for each element and doing the appropriate thing. This seems to me a better solution because I only get O(n + m) complexity.

So, the questions are:
- am I right in my calculations? 
- is there a better way that I have not thought about to accomplish what I want?

**UPDATE 19/06/2015**

So I've chosen the second case and it works OK. Here's my implementation in the wild

```c#
using (var he = new HostEntities())
{
    var dbHardDrives = he.HardDrive.Where(_ => _.HostName == _address).ToDictionary(_ => _.Name, _ => _);
    foreach (var dbHd in dbHardDrives)
    {
        if (wmiHardDrives.ContainsKey(dbHd.Key))
        {
            he.Entry(dbHd.Value).State = EntityState.Detached;
            he.Entry(wmiHardDrives[dbHd.Key]).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            he.Entry(dbHd.Value).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
    foreach (var wmiHd in wmiHardDrives)
    {
        if (!dbHardDrives.ContainsKey(wmiHd.Key))
        {
            he.Entry(wmiHd.Value).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }
    he.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning looks sound to me. LINQs `Except()` iterates over the second collection putting it into a <s>`HashSet`</s> [`Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060939/internal-system-linq-sett-vs-public-system-collections-generic-hashsett) before iterating over the first collection, performing lookups against the `Set` - it is O(n + m). Your extension method is therefore O(n + m) too. As you mention, if you want to calculate the 3 sets of additions, deletions and intersections, you would have to call it multiple times, making option 2 more preferable.

You are trying to do an outer join, and be able to evaluate the left, inner and right items separately. For an O(n + m) solution you could use something like this

```
public static JoinResult<TKey> JoinKeys<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second)
{
    var left = new List<TKey>();
    var inner = new HashSet<TKey>();    // HashSet to optimize lookups
    var right = new List<TKey>();

    foreach (var l in first.Keys)   // O(n)
    {
        if (second.ContainsKey(l))
            inner.Add(l);
        else
            left.Add(l);
    }

    foreach (var r in second.Keys)      // O(m)
    {
        if (!inner.Contains(r))
            right.Add(r);
    }

    return new JoinResult<TKey>
    {
        Left = left,
        Inner = inner,
        Right = right
    };
}

public class JoinResult<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Left { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Inner { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Right { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up implementing quite the same thing, see my updates.

Comment: Small remark - ***second*** collection is put into System.Linq.Set - a kind of HashSet, but simplier